# How to enforce express to interpret string as an HTML code?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm getting started with node.js and particularly express.js.

Given that I like to be as [D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible, I've decided to have only one `index.pug`-template which has single HTML element `main.content` in the body. The actual content is created by [`pug.renderFile()`](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugrenderfilepath-options-callback), based on excerpt, stored in `<name>.pug` file.

The whole picture is this:

**SERVER.JS**

```
response.render("index", {
    content: pug.renderFile(excerpt("aboutus"), {
        title: "About Us",
        subtitle: "Some subtitle here",
        article: "Some text here"
    })
});
```

**ABOUTUS.PUG**

```
h1= title
h3= subtitle
article= article
```

**INDEX.PUG**

```
//- html-head-body routine
main.content= content
```

The problem is that `pug.renderFile()` returns HTML code in form of string and, instead of getting three elements inside `main.content` element, I'm getting this exact string as `.innerHTML` of this element.

So, what is my mistake here?

Comment: Where are you getting excerpt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's horrible practice. You need to use extends. Not make two calls to pug. You're baking presentation into the wrong layer. This is going to sting you later.

Not to mention, you're forcing HTML into an intermediary string and making extra functions calls that can't be optimized away.

SERVER.JS

```
response.render("aboutus", {
  title: "About Us",
  subtitle: "Some subtitle here",
  article: "Some text here"
});
```

ABOUTUS.PUG

```
extends index

block content
  h1= title
  h3= subtitle
  article= article
```

INDEX.PUG

```
// html-head-body routine
main.content= content
```

If this doesn't make sense think about how your system is going to scale. Let's say you have one pug file for a navigation bar, one for a footer and one for a header etc. etc. You're going to string them all together and pass them into your `index.pug` on every request?

1. That will be very much anti-DRY.
2. That will be slow.
3. That will be memory intensive.
4. That will be a maintenance nightmare.

Follow [the convention](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) it will do you well.

Comment: Yeah, that is extremely convenient. Thank you very much!